# How to link assembly functions without a linker?

Tags: windows, assembly, 64-bit, nasm

I'm using NASM for some projects in Windows. I'd like to call C's `printf` function, but I don't want GCC with all it's burocracy, making my small project (assembly is actually 30 lines) in disassembled 24000 lines. How can I make linking ( get a function be called within system definitions, like MessageBox ) without a linker?

Edit:
I made it using a disassembler. It's funny to see that almost everything is add and nop.

```
0000000000402b90 <MessageBoxA>:
  402b90:   ff 25 2a 58 00 00       jmpq   *0x582a(%rip)        # 4083c0 <__imp_MessageBoxA>
  402b96:   90                      nop
  402b97:   90                      nop
  402b98:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  402b9f:   00
```

and `__imp_MessageBoxA`:

```
00000000004083c0 <__imp_MessageBoxA>:
  4083c0:   14 87                   adc    $0x87,%al
  4083c2:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4083c4:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
```

What does it actually do?

Comment: Get a smaller linker? ;)

Comment: @Jester that's so silly I literally laughed :P You know, I'm talking about executable code, not linker size.

Comment: NASM can generate .obj files which can be linked with the MS build tools.  But it seems unlikely to me that GCC's linker can't do what you want - unless you're using Cygwin?  (If so, try MinGW instead.)

Comment: Do you want to link to `printf()` or to some Win32 API that will display a message box with a specified string displayed?  Do you need formatting capabilities such as `printf()` provides or will you just be sending a string to be output?

Comment: @HarryJohnston NASM .o + MinGW GCC

Comment: @MichaelBurr I'd just use WinAPI if that's the case. I don't really need formatting.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you didn't have a problem until you tried to use printf?  That is, you can use the WinAPI without problems?  How do you generate the executable in that case?

Comment: @HarryJohnston (everybody in this question) I added info. Please look at it.

Comment: When the application is launched, the contents of the import table are overwritten by the loader, so the disassembly of `__imp_MessageBoxA` isn't meaningful.  I'm not familiar with the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can do C library linking manually. use following command on your object file produced with NASM:

```
ld -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 objectfile -lc
```

Above command tested on 64bit linux so if you want to use it on windows you must change `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` into your dynamic linker library usually find on `C:/cygwin/lib/..` if you are using cygwin and on `C:/MingW/msys/1.0/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` if you using MinGW.

Comment: This doesn't work on MinGW at all. Please, give us the Windows version.

Comment: @OP that doesn't actually work. There's no `msys` on my MinGW (I use MinGW-w64).

Comment: Ok you must install it with your MinGW installer. see [this](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) for details.

Comment: That looks like it would generate a Linux executable rather than a Windows one?

Comment: Msys just simulate linux environment on MinGW so at the end it create windows executable.